# Generate multiple JQ output documents from a single input, modifying each result

Tags: json, shell, loops, elasticsearch, jq

I want to do 2 operations in my JSON file . I tried to do it with JQ and SHELL .

First one : I want to tranform the parents elements to an pure text value

Second one : I want to remove one specific level in the JSON tree

Input :

```
    {
  "template_first": {
    "order": 0,
    "index_patterns": [
      "first"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "codec": "best_compression",
        "refresh_interval": "30s",
        "analysis": {
          "normalizer": {
            "norm_case_insensitive": {
              "filter": "lowercase",
              "type": "custom"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic": true,
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "strings": {
              "mapping": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "match_mapping_type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "log.id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "host.indexer.hostname": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "ts_indexer": {
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "template_second": {
    "order": 0,
    "index_patterns": [
      "second"
    ],
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "codec": "best_compression",
        "refresh_interval": "30s",
        "analysis": {
          "normalizer": {
            "norm_case_insensitive": {
              "filter": "lowercase",
              "type": "custom"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "number_of_replicas": "1"
      }
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "dynamic": true,
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "strings": {
              "mapping": {
                "type": "keyword"
              },
              "match_mapping_type": "string"
            }
          }
        ],
        "properties": {
          "log.id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "host.indexer.hostname": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "ts_indexer": {
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You see  there two JSON object in the file

```
    {
    "template_first" : { ...},
    "template_second" : { ... }
     }
```

**The first** modification comes from the appearance of this command

> PUT _template/template_number

instead of the key of the first JSON object.

So the expected result

```
PUT _template/template_first
  {...}
PUT _template/template_second
  {...}
```

**The second change** comes with the removal of _doc level

Before :

```
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": true,
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "mapping": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "match_mapping_type": "string"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "log.id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "host.indexer.hostname": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "ts_indexer": {
          "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Expected result

```
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "log.id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "host.indexer.hostname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "ts_indexer": {
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
```

So the actual result look like this

```
PUT _template/template_first
  {
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "first"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "codec": "best_compression",
      "refresh_interval": "30s",
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "norm_case_insensitive": {
            "filter": "lowercase",
            "type": "custom"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "log.id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "host.indexer.hostname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "ts_indexer": {
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT _template/template_second
  {
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "second"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "codec": "best_compression",
      "refresh_interval": "30s",
      "analysis": {
        "normalizer": {
          "norm_case_insensitive": {
            "filter": "lowercase",
            "type": "custom"
          }
        }
      },
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "1"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": true,
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "match_mapping_type": "string"
        }
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "log.id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "host.indexer.hostname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "ts_indexer": {
        "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I achieved to do the second change : delete one level of the JSON array  by using the command

```
jq  'keys[] as $k | map( .mappings =.mappings._doc   )' template.json
```

But i don't know how to do the first change and the 2nd change in the same time .

I tried  to loop into the array like this , without success

```
for row in $(jq 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)"' template.json); do
    _jq() {
     echo ${row} 
    }
   echo $(_jq '.name')
done
```

Comment: ...btw, can you build a simpler example of the operation you're trying to accomplish? The ES mapping definitions are pretty large/unwieldy; [mre] guidelines call for examples to be _minimal_ -- the shortest possible thing that can be run without changes to showcase your problem or test a solution.

Comment: Thank you Charles for your solutions . I'm trying to export thousand of templates from one cluster in version 6.8 to another one in 7.8 . I'm trying to automate it because i did not found a simple way to exports all template from v6.8 ES cluster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `jq` just once, and having it write a NUL-delimited list of template-name / modified-template-content pairs (which a bash `while read` loop can then iterate over):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' template_name && IFS= read -r -d '' template_content; do
  echo "We want to do PUT the following to _template/$template_name"
  printf '%s\n' "$template_content"
done < <(
  jq -j '
    to_entries[] |
    .key as $template_name |
    .value as $template_content |
    ($template_name, "\u0000",
     ($template_content | (.mappings = .mappings._doc) | tojson), "\u0000")
  ' <infile.json
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with the `done < <(` that caused syntax error in my shell (don't know why ) .
So I modified your script like this :

```
jq -j 'to_entries[] | .key as $template_name | .value as $template_content | ($template_name, "\u0000", ($template_content | (.mappings = .mappings._doc) | tojson), "\u0000")' < infile.json |
while IFS= read -r -d '' template_name && IFS= read -r -d '' template_content; do
  echo "PUT _template/$template_name"
  printf '%s\n' "$template_content"
done
```

Which perfectly does the job !
Thanks Charles

Comment: The process substitution requires your shell to actually be bash, not started with the name `sh`. Check that you weren't running `sh yourscript` or starting it with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang.

Comment: (The reason to prefer the process-substitution approach is the issues described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)).